# Crash while creating IBM ImqQueueManager class object

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I am creating an object of `ImqQueueManager` class like this

```cpp
ImqQueueManager mqManager;
```

Default constructor is getting called which is default initializing an object of `ImqObject` class.
Which is further leading to the crash. Here is the call stack

```
(gdb) bt full
#0 0x00007fb41179c336 in xcsCheckPointer () from /apps/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so
No symbol table info available.
#1 0x00007fb412101ccd in ImqTrc::checkWritePointer(void const*, unsigned long) () from /apps/mqm/lib64/libimqb23gl_r.so
No symbol table info available.
#2 0x00007fb412100264 in ImqStr::copy(char*, unsigned long, char const*, char) () from /apps/mqm/lib64/libimqb23gl_r.so
No symbol table info available.
#3 0x00007fb411fdd007 in ImqObj::setName(char const*) () from /apps/mqm/lib64/libimqc23gl_r.so
No symbol table info available.
#4 0x00007fb411fda4ee in ImqMgr::ImqMgr() () from /apps/mqm/lib64/libimqc23gl_r.so
```

**IBM MQ** version **7.5** is installed on this **64 bit Linux** machine.
Same code is working fine on another machine having the same **IBM MQ** version installed on that.

Can someone please help me to figure out what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Is it the same version of IBM MQ right down to the fix pack level? You only mention V7.5 and not the full V.R.M.F

Comment: Is the queue manager name the same between the crashing version and the working version?

Comment: Do you have any FDCs generated on the crashing system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IBM MQ version 7.5 is installed on this 64 bit Linux machine.

You are using a release of IBM MQ that is long out of support.  See [here](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6669) for a list of [IBM MQ End of Service Dates](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6669).

Secondly, you should be showing us your code (update your post) because otherwise we will just be guessing.

Here's a fully functioning C++ that will connect to a remote queue manager and put a message to a queue.

```
/*
 * Program Name
 *  MQTest31.cpp
 *
 * Description
 * Test program to connect to a queue manager using MQCONNX and MQCSP
 * and then put a message from a queue.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *   QMgrName ChlName hostname(port) QName
 *
 * Where
 *    QMgrName is the queue manager name
 *    ChlName is the name of the channel to be used
 *    hostname(port) is the hostname and port number
 *    QName is the queue name
 * i.e.
 *    MQTest31.exe MQWT1 TEST.CHL 127.0.0.1(1415) TEST.Q1
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix, Capitalware Inc.
 */

 /*
  * Standard Include files
  */
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <imqi.hpp>    /* MQI */

/*
 * mainline
 */
int main ( int argc, char * * argv )
{
   /* --------------------------------------------
    * Variable declarations.
    * --------------------------------------------
    */
   ImqQueueManager  mgr;
   ImqChannel      *pchannel = 0 ;
   ImqQueue         queue;
   ImqMessage       msg;
   /* */
   char     buffer[10240];
   char     myUserId[33]   = "roger";
   char     myPassword[33] = "mypwd";
   char     testMsg[] = "This is a simple test message.";

   /* --------------------------------------------
    * Code section
    * --------------------------------------------
    */
   if (argc != 5)
   {
     cout << "Usage: MQTest31 QMgrName ChlName hostname(port) QName" <<endl;
     return( 1 );
   }

   cout << "MQTest31 Starting." <<endl;

   // Create object descriptor for subject queue
   mgr.setName( argv[ 1 ] );

   pchannel = new ImqChannel ;
   pchannel -> setHeartBeatInterval( 1 );
   pchannel -> setTransportType( MQXPT_TCP );
   pchannel -> setChannelName( argv[ 2 ] );
   pchannel -> setConnectionName( argv[ 3 ] );

   mgr.setChannelReference( pchannel );

   queue.setName( argv[ 4 ] );

   /*
    * Specify UserId and Password via MQCSP
    */
   mgr.setAuthenticationType(MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD);
   mgr.setUserId( myUserId );
   mgr.setPassword( myPassword );

   /*
    * Connect to queue manager
    */
   if ( ! mgr.connect( ) )
   {
     cout << "MQTest31: connect CC=" << mgr.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << mgr.reasonCode() <<endl;
     return( 1 );
   }

   /* setup queue info */
   queue.setConnectionReference( mgr );
   queue.setOpenOptions(MQOO_OUTPUT + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
   queue.open( );
   cout << "MQTest31: open CC=" << queue.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << queue.reasonCode() <<endl;

   if ( queue.completionCode( ) == MQCC_OK )
   {
      msg.useEmptyBuffer( buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
      msg.setMessageId( );
      msg.setCorrelationId( );
      msg.setFormat( MQFMT_STRING );      /* character string format    */
      strcpy(buffer,  testMsg);
      msg.setMessageLength( (int)strlen( buffer ) );

      queue.put(msg);
      cout << "MQTest31: put CC=" << queue.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << queue.reasonCode() <<endl;
   }

   /* Close the queue */
   queue.close( );
   cout << "MQTest31: close CC=" << queue.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << queue.reasonCode() <<endl;

   /* Disconnect from the queue manager */
   mgr.disconnect( );
   cout << "MQTest31: disconnect CC=" << mgr.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << mgr.reasonCode() <<endl;

   /* clean up */
   if ( pchannel )
   {
      mgr.setChannelReference( );
      delete pchannel ;
   }

   cout << "MQTest31 Ending." <<endl;
   return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't share the whole code. Its a huge code having 32 files. This code is working fine on all other machines. There also we have the same MQ version installed. But on one particular machine I am getting this crash. If we take an example of your code. What could be the reason if your code crashes on one particular machine at line `ImqQueueManager  mgr;`?

Comment: See new posting.

Answer (score 0):

You provide so little information that it is almost impossible to help you.

> Its a huge code having 32 files.

I seriously doubt your MQ code is spread across 32 files.  Because that would be a very bad design.

Questions that need complete answers (update your original posting):

1. Is your C++ application connecting in bindings or client mode?
2. If your C++ application connects in bindings, are you setting the queue manager name or relying on default values?  (i.e. setName method).  Also, issue the ***dspmq*** command where your C++ application runs, what does it show?  Is there a default queue manager highlighted?
3. Is your C++ application running on the same server as the queue manager or a different server?
4. What release of MQ was used to compile and link your C++ application?
5. What release of MQ is used when you run your C++ application?
6. On the servers where your application works, what release of MQ is used?
7. Did you run an MQ trace on the server where your C++ application runs?
8. Did you open a ticket (PMR) with IBM yet?

Note: When I say what release of MQ, I want the 4 digit version number.  i.e. v7.5.0.3 or whatever it is.